# Is it nessesarry to send credentials on every single request to MVC Web Api?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api

I am about to create my first restfull web service where i chose MVC WEB API to be the "provider". After reading about authentication i am a little confused.

My requirements is that on call to any url of webservice i want client to be authenticated, except sign in url.

I understand the flow this way:  after client is signed, webservice returns a authenticationtoken which client have to store, and send to the server on every request in the headers. But where is this token stored on the webservice?

I am very confused at which flow of actions i have to implement if i want to avoid users to pass login parameters on every single request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically how this works is that the user's authentication token will be stored in a cookie. Once you authenticate the user, you will create a 'session' for them server side. There will be a 'session token' that corresponds with this session.

When the user signs in, you will create a new session for them. This will send them a new cookie. Every future request they make will contain this cookie. You will then use this cookie to identify the user's session. From it, you can draw their username, etc.

It sounds like what you really want is the .net State management (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s(v=vs.140).aspx). You should look into using this, and see how you can apply it to your current needs.

In the long run, once you've got proper user session tokens, you will not need to send their credentials with every request. The session token will be good enough to identity the user upon every request that they make.